# Putting my Django form into HTML

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a drop-down list of member IDs for users to choose from. I created a form called **SelectForm** in **forms.py**:

```
from .models import Member
from django import forms 

class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'

class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    memberid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Member.objects.values_list('member_id', flat=True))
```

**With the view:**

```
class SelectView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'expcore/select_member.html'
  model = Member

  def select_member(request):
    form = SelectForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = SelectForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/questions/')
    else:
      form = SelectForm()
    return render(request, 'select_member.html', {'form': form})
```

Right now, all the HTML gives me is 'Member Selection: Please blablablabla' with a LIST of bullet points that correspond to the number of existing member IDs. However, the actual member IDs don't show up; furthermore, the whole thing is in a list format right now and not a drop-down menu, which I want.

**select_member.html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<title>Member Selection</title>

<h1>Member Selection</h1>

Please select your Member ID from the drop-down menu.

<ul>
{% for member_id in object_list %}
    <li><a href='/member/{{ member.name }}'></a></li>

{% empty %}
    <li>None available.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I believe the form I created is supposed to generate a drop-down menu for me but I don't think I'm getting the view/HTML right. Can you guys help me out?

Also - member IDs is under the class Member in my **models.py:**

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.SlugField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're not using the object form in your template. And, what is the `object_list` variable??? I don't see it in your view.
To display the object form you can use: `{{ form }}` in your template.

Comment: @AngelCruijff where would I put {{ form }} exactly? Do I need to remove anything?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this third party application: [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It will make your life way easier.

Answer (score 0):

In your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<title>Member Selection</title>

<h1>Member Selection</h1>

Please select your Member ID from the drop-down menu.

<!-- Form -->
<form method="POST" action="your_view">
{{ form }}
</form

<ul>
    {% for member_id in object_list %}
        <li><a href='/member/{{ member.name }}'></a></li>

        {% empty %}
        <li>None available.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Replaced "your_view" with both "select_member" and "SelectView", but nothing shows up :/